# Codeigniter : POST data- attributes HTML5

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I'm currently using the CodeIgniter's Framework and I have a problem with data- attributes in HTML5 and I don't know how to pass data-attributes from a dropdown input in my form.

I know how to do it with jQuery but I don't know if is there any "solutions" to get the data attributes and recognize my type of data.

This is my code for the drop:

```
<select name="username">
<option value="1" data-attributes="users">Simon</option>
<option value="1" data-attributes="collectives">My super crew</option>
</select>
```

Thaks in advance if you have some lights for me.

Simon

Comment: So, you want to get the Value of data-attributes in PHP?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 5):

`data-*` attributes are designed to be handled by client side code.

If you want to submit data in a form, then use the `value` attribute.

```
<option value="users">Simon</option>
<option value="collectives">My super crew</option>
```

You can encode multiple different pieces of data there if you like.

e.g. pipe separated data:

```
<option value="1|users">Simon</option>
<option value="1|collectives">My super crew</option>
```

e.g. JSON:

```
<option value="{&quot;number&quot;: 1, &quot;string&quot;: %quot;users%quot;}">Simon</option>
<option value="{&quot;number&quot;: 1, &quot;string&quot;: %quot;collectives%quot;}">My super crew</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said: Only "value" is submitted by the Browser.

Anoter solution would be to hava a hidden input field which value gets set to the data-attributes value when the select is changed (via javascript).