# Read Checkbox Data Attribute in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, custom-data-attribute

I have a checkbox with a data attribute attached to it:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="plugins[]" 
       value="google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp" 
       data-path="gadwp" 
       checked="checked" /> 
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP<br>
```

Is it possible to access the "path" data attribute directly through PHP? I need this checkbox to be able to pass two values and also provide a readable name ("Google Analytics Dashboard for WP)

Comment: Well, I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343345/codeigniter-post-data-attributes-html5 Looks like piping may be the answer

Comment: How about `name="plugins[gadwp]"`

Comment: The linked post is for options in a select. There's really no other way for options, but checkboxes there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Piping is the solution I was looking for.

Updated code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="plugins[]" value="google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp|gadwp" checked="checked" /> Google Analytics Dashboard for WP<br>
```

PHP:

```
$plugin = explode('|', $plugin);

echo "plugin value 1: " . $plugin[0];
echo "plugin value 2: " . $plugin[1];
```

Comment: Why when you can just put it in the array as the key?

Comment: "gadwp" is a value not a key name

Comment: Make it a key name then you can get it when you get the value: `name="plugins[gadwp]"`

Answer (score 0):

No, that data is not posted to the server on submit.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jquery.. you can

```
$('container').attr('data-path');
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a PHP only solution. Piping is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another work-around in case it is useful:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
               name="plugins[checked]" 
               value="google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp" 
               data-path="gadwp" 
               checked="checked" /> 
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP<br>
<input type="hidden" name="plugins[path]" value="gadwp">
<input type="hidden" name="plugins[name]" value="Google Analytics Dashboard for WP">
```

And then on the php side you would check if the checkbox is checked to get the hidden input values. Something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['plugins']['checked'])) {
    $path = $_POST['plugins']['path'];
    $name = $_POST['plugins']['name'];
}
```